# Need help to get specific <key,Value> pair depeding upon a sinlge value from values in a Map

Tags: flutter, dictionary, oop, dart

I am trying to get <key,Value> pairs thorugh a single value from values of map.
I am trying to display all the books that have status = true.
But i don't know how can i access status from librarian class(as status is member variable of Book class) and how i can get to the column of status as there are many value for each key.
**BOOK CLASS**

```
class Book {
  String BookID = '';
  String Author ='';
  String Name='';
  int RackNo=0;
  int Price = 0;
  bool status = true;
  int Edition = 0;
  String DateOfPurchase='';
  static var count=0;
  static var BookList = <String,Object>{};
  Book(String BookID , String Author,String Name, int RackNo,int Price, bool status,int Edition,String DateOfPurchase){
    this.BookID=BookID;
    this.Author=Author;
    this.Name=Name;
    this.RackNo=RackNo;
    this.Price=Price;
    this.status=status;
    this.Edition=Edition;
    this.DateOfPurchase=DateOfPurchase;
    BookList[this.BookID]={this.Name, this.Author,this.Name,this.RackNo,this.Price,this.status,this.Edition,this.DateOfPurchase};
    count++;
  }

  void DisplayBookDetails(String ID){
    print(BookList[ID]);
  }
  void UpDateStatus(bool newStatus){
    status=newStatus;
  }
}
```

**Librarian Class**

```
import 'package:untitled2/Book.dart';
class Librarian  {
  int count=0;
  String Name = '';
  String Password = '';
  Librarian(String Name,String Password){
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Password=Password;
  }
  void SearchBook(String ID){
    print(Book.BookList[ID]);
  }
  void ShowAvailableBooks() {
    Book.BookList.values.forEach((element) {print(element);});
  }
}
```

**what i am trying to achieve is something like this**

```
if(Book.BookList.values.status==true)//all the books tha have status == true 
{
print(Book.BookList[ID's of those books])//display all those books
}
```

Sorry in advance for poor Question Composition as it is my first time asking a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example. I changed your classes around because they were constructed weirdly and you had `bookList` as a `static` variable within `Book`, which wouldn't really work. The main functionality you asked for is in the `showAvailableBooks` function.

```
class Book {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String? author;
  final int? rackNo;
  final int? price;
  final int? edition;
  final String? dateOfPurchase;
  bool status;
  
  Book({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    this.author,
    this.rackNo,
    this.price,
    this.edition,
    this.dateOfPurchase,
    this.status = false,
  });

  void set setStatus(bool newStatus) {
    status = newStatus;
  }
  
  void printBook() {
    print('id: $id, title: $title, author: $author');
  }
}

class Librarian {
  final String name;
  final String password;
  
  Map<String, Book> books = {};
  int count = 0;
  
  Librarian({required this.name, required this.password});
  
  void addBooks(List<Book> bookList) {
    for (Book book in bookList) {
      books[book.id] = book;
      count += 1;
    }
  }
  
  void displayBookDetails(String id) {
    books[id]?.printBook();
  }

  //The function you want
  void showAvailableBooks() {
    List<String> available = books.keys.where((id) => books[id]!.status == true).toList();
    for (String bookID in available) {
      books[bookID]?.printBook();
    }
  }
}

void main() {
  Librarian librarian = Librarian(
    name: "Mrs. Librarian",
    password: "Password123",
  );
  
  //Unavailable - status: false
  Book book1 = Book(
    id: 'abc-123',
    title: 'Book 1',
    author: 'Author One',
  );
  
  //Available - status: true
  Book book2 = Book(
    id: 'def-456',
    title: 'Book 2',
    author: 'Author Two',
    status: true
  );
  
  //Available - status: true
  Book book3 = Book(
    id: 'ghi-789',
    title: 'Book 3',
    author: 'Author Three',
    status: true
  );
  
  librarian.addBooks([book1, book2, book3]);
  
  /*The function you want - prints only books with status: true*/
  print('Before changing book1 status to true');
  librarian.showAvailableBooks();
  
  book1.setStatus = true;
  
  print('\nAfter changing book1 status to true');
  librarian.showAvailableBooks();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. I was using static because i saw that i can access it in librarian class I am a beginner in OOP. Now i can see how to construct a class properly and work with maps better.